# How do I execute a program which contains two classes independently in eclipse?

Tags: java, applet, frame

How do I execute below code in eclipse as one program?

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;

   public class Keyframe extends Applet
 {
      Frame f;
      public void init()
      {
          f= new FrameHandlingUsingApplet("tarun");
          f.setSize(300,300);
          f.setVisible(true);
      }
      public void start()
      {
          f.setVisible(true);
      }
      public void stop()
      {
          f.setVisible(false);
      }
      public void paint(Graphics g)
      {
          g.drawString("this is applet window ", 20, 50);
      }
      public class FrameHandlingUsingApplet extends Frame
      {
        FrameHandlingUsingApplet(String name)
        {
            super(name);
            addWindowListener(new MyWindowAdapter(this));

        }
        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            g.drawString("this is frame window", 20, 30);
        }

        public class MyWindowAdapter extends WindowAdapter
        {
            FrameHandlingUsingApplet window;
            MyWindowAdapter(FrameHandlingUsingApplet window)
            {
                this.window=window;
            }
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent m)
            {
                window.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
      }
 }
`enter code here`.*;
'

import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;

   public class Keyframe extends Applet
 {
      Frame f;
      public void init()
      {
          f= new FrameHandlingUsingApplet("tarun");
          f.setSize(300,300);
          f.setVisible(true);
      }
      public void start()
      {
          f.setVisible(true);
      }
      public void stop()
      {
          f.setVisible(false);
      }
      public void paint(Graphics g)
      {
          g.drawString("this is applet window ", 20, 50);
      }
      public class FrameHandlingUsingApplet extends Frame
      {
        FrameHandlingUsingApplet(String name)
        {
            super(name);
            addWindowListener(new MyWindowAdapter(this));

        }
        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            g.drawString("this is frame window", 20, 30);
        }

        public class MyWindowAdapter extends WindowAdapter
        {
            FrameHandlingUsingApplet window;
            MyWindowAdapter(FrameHandlingUsingApplet window)
            {
                this.window=window;
            }
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent m)
            {
                window.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
      }
 }
```

Comment: help me in solving this code. Thanks in advance

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT using components in favor of Swing.

Answer (score 1):

You import the other class using the import statement which points to the other class. For example if your class is contained in package:

```
import packagename.ClassName;
```